# Is there a JavaScript equivalent for Swift's @dynamicMemberLookup?

Tags: javascript, propertydescriptor

In Swift I can define a type which returns the name of a requested property as string using `@dynamicMemberLookup`:

```swift
@dynamicMemberLookup struct S {
  subscript(dynamicMember member: String) -> String { member }
}

let s = S()
s.foo  // returns "foo"
s.bar  // returns "bar"
```

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in JavaScript? In some sense, I'm looking for a way to override `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`. I thought something like the following would've worked, but it's not.

```js
const cachedGOPD = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor = function (o, p) {
  if (o instanceof S) return { get() { return p } }
  return cachedGOPD(o, p)
}
```

I don't know if `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` is called when requesting an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technically achievable with a Proxy, no need to modify `getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```js
const makeS = () => new Proxy({}, {
  get(_, prop) {
    console.log('getter called on', prop);
    return prop;
  }
});

const s = makeS()
console.log(s.foo)  // returns "foo"
console.log(s.bar)  // returns "bar"
```

It's an interesting theoretical exercise, but in practice, proxies are slow, and this is a bit weird. In most cases, well-designed code shouldn't need to rely on such a thing.